# Can an overstayed student visa affect when applying another student visa for another country?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals

I overstayed my student visa for 2 years in New Zealand and came back to india voluntary, without a deportation stamp on my passport, just an arrival stamp at Delhi airport

Now I want to apply for a student visa in Europe. Will this affect my application?

Answer (score 4):

## Yes, it can *affect* your application.

- As a student, you have to apply for a *national* D visa if you want to go to a Schengen nation, or a similar national visa otherwise. Details vary from country to country and are best asked on [Expatriates stack exchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/).
- Questions on the form might be if you have ever been denied a visa or been deported, or if you have ever overstayed a visa.
- If they ask about overstay and you tell the truth, your credibility will take a hit because you violated the NZ visa rules. Your application must show that you have put your life in order.
- If they ask and you lie, and if you get caught, your chances for a visa will be gone. They really don't like that.

We advise telling the truth. You might get away with a lie once, but not forever, so better come clean. Proven deception is worse than an admitted overstay.